# é and other special characters crash my app when being passed into a URL

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been doing some searching and can't seem to be sure or work around when special characters are included in text.

How would I go about cleaning up special characters within Swift?

The scenario is I have a function

```
GoogleAPI().getBusinessInfo(googleUrl: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=\(business.alias)
```

This function will then make an API call to get data, nothing fancy. However, I'm crashing when I come across é.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to percent encode your query items. The easiest way is to use URLComponents:

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents()
urlComponents.scheme = "https"
urlComponents.host = "maps.googleapis.com"
urlComponents.path = "/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json"
let value = "café"  // business.alias
urlComponents.queryItems = [.init(name: "input", value: value)]

if let googleUrl = urlComponents.url {
    print(googleUrl)
    // GoogleAPI().getBusinessInfo(googleUrl: googleUrl)
}
```

---

This will print

> "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=caf%C3%A9\n"